# Live DLNA Streaming on Mac OS X

Tags: streaming, dlna

I have the DLNA server [mediatomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) installed on my Mac. What I would like to do now is to capture my Mac's screen and to stream it live through mediatomb.

Is there any software able to do it?

Comment: AFAIK, MediaTomb only works on files – live streaming isn't intended. MediaTomb [uses FIFOs to transcode stuff](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/transcoding) on the fly, so you could theoretically "pipe" data to the receiving devices. That would mean you'd only have to tell MediaTomb to read from your screen capture file. QuickTime creates a temporary file when you start recording your screen, but you'd have to find out where that is first.

Comment: But … as you can see, this is a hacky solution. Where do you want to stream it to and why does it need to be DLNA?

Comment: Need to stream it to an external television which supports DLNA.